# Issue installing package testthat R on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: r, ubuntu, package, ubuntu-18.04, install.packages

I'm new to Ubuntu and can't install testthat.
Running
`install.packages('testthat')`
yields the following output:

```
Installing package into ‘/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/testthat_2.0.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 217071 bytes (211 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 211 KB

* installing *source* package ‘testthat’ ...
** package ‘testthat’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -DCOMPILING_TESTTHAT     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-i39faS/r-base-3.5.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c init.c -o init.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -DCOMPILING_TESTTHAT     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-i39faS/r-base-3.5.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c reassign.c -o reassign.o
g++  -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -DCOMPILING_TESTTHAT     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-i39faS/r-base-3.5.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c test-catch.cpp -o test-catch.o
g++  -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -DCOMPILING_TESTTHAT     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-i39faS/r-base-3.5.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c test-example.cpp -o test-example.o
g++  -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -DCOMPILING_TESTTHAT     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-i39faS/r-base-3.5.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c test-runner.cpp -o test-runner.o
g++ -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o testthat.so init.o reassign.o test-catch.o test-example.o test-runner.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/testthat/libs
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
*** copying figures
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (testthat)

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpYhp7aJ/downloaded_packages’
```

When I try to use the function expect_equal(), I'm met with
`could not find function "expect_equal"`

Is this an issue with permissions? Is there a secure way to resolve it?

p.s. please excuse ignorance and any lack of etiquette on my part, and please inform me of proper protocols.

Comment: you installed, you just need to use ```library(testthat)``` before trying to use expect_equal

Comment: Thanks very much. That solved it.